# Орать и... орать — омонимы?

Tags: омонимы, однокоренные-слова

Возвращаясь к вопросу об "орале", хочу еще спросить: орать в значении "пахать" и орать в значении "кричать" имеют общий корень или просто случайным образом похожи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, происхождение совершенно разное, от разных праиндоевропейских морфов.

I ора́ть I " пахать", орю́, орёшь, укр. орю́, ора́ти, др.-русск., ст.-слав. орати, орѭ ἀροτριᾶν (Остром.), болг. ора́, сербохорв. о̀рати, о̀ре̑м, словен. oráti, оrа̑m, órjem, чеш. orati, слвц. оrаt᾽, польск. оrаć, orzę, в.-луж. worać, н.-луж. woraś. Родственно лит. árti, ariù, ariaũ, лтш. ar̂t, аr̨u "нахать", лат. аrō, -ārе – то же, греч. ἀρόω " пашу", ср.-ирл. airim – то же, гот. аrjаn " пахать", тохар. АВ ārе " плуг", д.-в.-н. аrt "вспаханное поле", а также ра́ло, ра́тай. Вероятно, первонач. атематический гл.; см. Вальде–Гофм. 1, 69; Траутман, ВSW 13; Мейе–Вайан 85; М.–Э. 1, 141; Шпехт, KZ 66, 29; Бенвенист, Festschr. Н. Hirt 2, 234. Сюда же Шпехт (KZ 68, 42) относит лит. ìrti "расходиться в стороны, разделяться, расщепляться", ст.-слав. орити λύειν, καθαιρεῖν (см. разори́ть).

II ора́ть II, ору́, орёшь, сербохорв. о̀рити се, о̀рим се "отдаваться (о звуке)". Вероятно, родственно др.-инд. вед. ā́rуаti "восхваляет, превозносит", греч. ἀρή, атт. ἀρά̄ "молитва", ἀράομαι "молюсь, умоляю", ἀρύω "кричу, говорю", ἀρύει ̇ ἀντιλέγει, βοα ̇ ἀρύουσαι ̇ λέγουσαι, κελεύουσαι, ἀρύσασθαι ̇ ἐπικαλέσθαι, ἤρυσεν. ἐβόησεν ἤ ἐβόα (Гесихий, Еtуm. Маgn.), лат. ōrō, ōrārе "говорить; просить", хетт. arii̯a- "спрашивать, подобно оракулу", aruwa(i̯)- "почитать", арм. uranam "отрицаю"; см. Гофман, Gr. Wb.21; Вальде–Гофм. 2, 224; Сольмсен, KZ 35, 484; Мейе, ВSL 26, 19 и сл.; В. Шульце, Qu. ер. 90.

(Фасмер)

Answer (score 0):

Хм.. ни в коем случае не утверждение, а остороооожненькое такое предположение...
Если сопоставить *вещать*, *вещий* - и *вещи*, *реку*, *речь* - и укр. *речi*(вещи),
то нельзя ли предположить, что в совсем уж седой древности между понятиями *издавать определённые звуки* и *создавать материальные ценности* стоял знак равенства?

Может, тогда и землю обрабатывали с помощью крика определённой вибрации.
Тогда *орать* (пахать) и *орать* (кричать) не омонимы, а одно и то же слово.