# Орать и... орать.

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Слова "орать" в смысле "кричать" и "орать" — "пахать" однокоренные или случайно похожи?

Comment: Когда пишешь новый заголовок нового вопроса, то системой выдаются похожие или идентичные заголовки. Не заметить этого довольно трудно. Но одинаковые вопросы задаются регулярно и настойчиво, сам такое допустил однажды, каюсь...

Answer (score 1):

[уже обсуждалось](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/12634/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B)